# Groupby multiple and count in Javascipt

Tags: javascript

I am a new learner of Javascript. I have one question about the findIndex function.

Here I want to do the counting based on name_station and result_run.

```
const res = runs.reduce((acc, obj) => {
   const existingIndex = acc.findIndex(
        el => el.name_station === obj.name_station && el.result_run === obj.result_run
        )
   console.log(existingIndex)
   if (existingIndex > -1) {
       acc[existingIndex].count += 1
   } else {
       acc.push({
       station: obj.name_station,
       result: obj.result_run,
       count: 1
       })
   }
   return acc
}, [])
        
console.log(res)
```

Below is my data

```
const runs = [
  { name_station: 'fpc10', result_run: true },
  { name_station: 'fpc10', result_run: false },
  { name_station: 'fpc10', result_run: true },
  { name_station: 't10', result_run: true }
]
```

Here when I print the existingIndex, it return all -1 (which means the condition in el doesn't meet), but actually there are some matched value in my data.

My expected output would be like this

```
{ name_station: "fpc10", result_run: "true", count: 2 }, 
{ name_station: "fpc10", result_run: "false", count: 1 }, 
{ name_station: "t10", result_run: "true", count:1 }
```

Please help me to check that whether I did something wrong or missing something. Thanks in advance!

Comment: That's ignore your res function first, What result do you want?

Comment: Hello @Joseph Wang, I have edited the question with my expected output. Thanks!

Comment: try return this `(el.name_station === obj.name_station) && (el.result_run === obj.result_run)` in the findIndex method.

Comment: It's not working because you push `{ result: true }` instead of `{ result_run: true }`

Comment: Same for the station actually, you named it "station" in your acc and not "name_station"

Comment: Can I ask why you want your expected output `result_run` to be string instead of boolean?

Answer (score 0):

This line of your: `el => el.name_station === obj.name_station && el.result_run === obj.result_run`

should be: `el => el.station === obj.name_station && el.result === obj.result_run`

Just change the object fields :)